# Is this proof of Schur's lemma (for a densely defined closed operator) mistaken? How to fix it?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, representation-theory

I'm trying to understand a version of Schur's lemma for a densely defined closed operator.  It is on page 17 of the book *Nonabelian Harmonic Analysis* by Howe and Tan. The confusing parts are underlined in red.

[image]

First of all, since the image of $P_U|_{\Gamma (T)}$ is the domain of $T$, which is a dense subspace of $U$, it seems like the image of $U_1$ should be $U$, not just $(\ker T)^\perp$.  Secondly, what does $\Gamma(T) \cap V =\{0\}$ have to do with T being closed?  This should be a consequence of the fact that $T$ is a function.

So it seems like what actually needs to be shown is that $U_1$ carries $(\ker P_V)^\perp$ isometrically onto $(\ker T)^\perp$.  $U_1$ looks like an isometry, so that's okay.  Also, $P_U|_{\Gamma(T)}$ clearly carries $\ker P_V|_{\Gamma(T)}$ onto $\ker T$, so if $P_1:=   (P_U|_{\Gamma(T)}^\ast \circ P_U|_{\Gamma(T)})^{1/2}$ preserved $\ker P_V$ maybe I would be in business, but it's only evident to me that $P_U|_{\Gamma(T)}^\ast \circ P_U|_{\Gamma(T)}$ does so.

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have found a solution.  Any feedback would be appreciated.  Write $P_U$ (resp $P_V$) for $P_U|_{\Gamma(T)}$ (resp $P_V|_{\Gamma(T)}$).

We want to show that $U_1$ maps $(\ker P_V)^\perp$ isometrically onto $(\ker T)^\perp$.  Since $U_1$ is a Hilbert space isomorphism, it suffices to show that $U_1$ maps $\ker P_V$ onto $\ker T$.

Take $(u, 0) \in \ker P_V$.  It is easy to seee that $P_U^\ast P_U (u,0)=(u,0)$. Therefore, since $P_1 = (P_U^\ast P_U)^{1/2}$ is the limit of polynomials in  $P_U^\ast P_U$ in the strong operator topology, and since $P_1$ is an involution of $\ker P_V$ (since its square is $P_U^\ast P_U$), we see that $P_1$ restricts to a vector space isomorphism of $\ker P_V$.   Therefore, $(u,0) = P_1 (w,0)$ for some other $(w,0) \in \ker P_V$.  Since $(w,0) \in \Gamma(T)$, this means $w \in \ker T$, and we have

$$U(u,0)=UP_1(w,0)=P_U(w,0)=w\in \ker T$$

Converseley, if $a\in \ker T$, then $(a,0) \in \ker P_V$, so that $P_1(a,0)=(b,0)$ for some $(b,0)\in \ker P_V$.  We therefore have

$$a = P_U(a,0)=UP_1(a,0)=U(b,0).  \square$$